# How to package sqlite3 in node.js executable packages?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, zeit-pkg

I want to make use of a simple database in a compiled node.js app. Is this possible without installing the database separately? i.e I want the database to be included in the .exe file so that I can just copy and execute that file.

I'm using `pkg` to create .exe files and it works well, but when I use the [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) npm module the .exe errors when I try to execute with the following warning:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1155
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\snapshot\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v51-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1252:46)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1136:31)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\sqlite\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1226:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Which looks similar to a sqlite3 bug that was fixed here: https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/183 (since the bug was fixed I assume this is a user issue)

Looking at the error message, it looks like the `...../bide_sqlit3.node` file can't be found. And looking at `node_modules/` in my development env (where the module works) I can't find that file. So I assume that the file is NOT being included in the executable and that I need to do something that:

1. Makes `pkg` include the file in the binary
2. Alters the path to the file to be the path to the file in the binary

How do I do this with `zeit/pkg`? or, if this is more correct: How do I force npm to to install binaries to node_modules and then reference those binaries?

Comment: did you resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't remember... Sorry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put the built node-sqlite3.node in the same directory as the binary that you built with pkg (as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/pkg/issues/141)). This file can be found in your node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-vxx-xxxxx-xxx/node_sqlite3.node.

You also need to make sure that you build your project with pkg with the same node version that you built sqlite3 with.

Comment: This doesn't work see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789200/how-to-use-pkg-to-make-node-app-an-executable-with-a-native-dependency

Comment: @simon-p-r: My answer also reflects the pkg manual (https://github.com/zeit/pkg#native-addons), so your issue might then be a bug in pkg.

Comment: @simon-p-r The question you've linked has been deleted. Can you elaborate on why exactly this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your package.json:

```js
"pkg": {
    "assets": ["node_modules/sqlite3/lib/bindings"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full gitlab ci solution for Linux environments:

My `package.json` have this section:

```
  "bin": "src/app.js",
  "pkg": {
    "targets": [
      "node16-linux-x64"
    ],
    "assets": [
      "node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-glibc-x64/node_sqlite3.node"
    ],
    "outputPath": "./"
  }
```

My gitlab ci pipeline:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 1
  APT_CACHE_DIR: .aptcache/
  YARN_CACHE_DIR: .yarn-cache/
  PKG_CACHE_DIR: .pkg-cache/

build-deploy:
  image: node:16.13-slim
  cache:
    key: backend
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - $APT_CACHE_DIR
      - $YARN_CACHE_DIR
      - $PKG_CACHE_DIR
  before_script:
    - rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
    - mkdir -pv $APT_CACHE_DIR $YARN_CACHE_DIR $PKG_CACHE_DIR && mkdir /var/cache/apt/archives && mount --bind $APT_CACHE_DIR /var/cache/apt/archives/
    - apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
    - apt install rsync openssh-client sqlite3 -y
    - node -v && yarn -v
    - yarn install --cache-folder $YARN_CACHE_DIR
  script:
    - PKG_CACHE_PATH=$PKG_CACHE_DIR node_modules/.bin/pkg package.json
    # deploy via rsync
```

Please note:

- you need the `sqlite3` package in your build system, otherwise you will not have necessary binding under `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/`. Here you can see I am installing `sqlite3` package in my debian system.
- if you will build on alpine linux and then deploy to debian\ubuntu\gentoo release environment it will not work since alpine use `musl` and most other linux systems use `glibc`. You must build on same system that you will use in release